# Unable to login using mechanize

Tags: python, authorization, mechanize, multipartform-data

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

br = Browser()

# Browser options
# Ignore robots.txt. Do not do this without thought and consideration.
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Don't add Referer (sic) header
br.set_handle_referer(False)

# Don't handle Refresh redirections
br.set_handle_refresh(False)

#Setting the user agent as firefox
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

br.open('http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com')
br.select_form(name="loginForm")
br['loginid'] = "username"
br['password']="password"
br.hiddenfield="310a7b2cd0e52dd19c9bbe4c78f1eb6778af88a67a5990969273711054584e037c3bee2f22ea5ebfe7cb6b3d151f54b87c0b232f5424fb54ebdf64f590e9e913"
br.submit()

#Getting the response in beautifulsoup
soup = BS(br.response().read(),"html.parser")

for product in soup.find_all('td', class_="MTTD1"):

    #printing product name and url
    print "Product Name : " + product.a.text
    #print "Product Url : " + product.a["href"]
    print "======================="
```

I have tried logging in to the above mentioned website using python mechanize.
But it gives the following error.

> " ValueError: unknown POST form encoding type
>   'multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8' "

Comment: If you don't get a useful answer to your question you might consider switching to selenium. (You mightn't know about it?) In contrast with mechanize which was last uploaded in 2011, this product is being actively developed and many people are using it. It's quite easy to get started with it too. See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html.

Comment: Thanks, @BillBell tried the same using selenium as well , worked pretty well :)

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using **requests**. Turns out that I was not submitting all the details that the end-point expects. For future references anyone looking to submit any forms using POST make sure you submit all the form parameters that the end point expects. These parameters have a attribute name in their tags or You could also do Ctrl+Shift+I and look for the form parameters in the Network section.